# A question I submitted as a guest was removed. How can I recover the question, and why was it removed without any feedback?

Tags: discussion, support

I submitted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1636119/how-can-i-manage-a-company-facebook-page-as-an-employee-without-providing-phot) as a guest, while logged out.

For reasons unknown the post was removed. Perhaps it was deemed unsuitable for Superuser or whatever, but in any case I would like to recover the text of the question so I can edit it and/or post it elsewhere.

Additionally I think it is extremely poor that a question would be removed without leaving even a trace and without providing feedback to the author. It's extremely frustrating. I think deleted questions should be kept directly linkable (as long as they aren't offensive) but simply de-listed from the site and search results.

Can someone please recover the text of the question?

Comment: “I think deleted questions should be kept directly linkable (as long as they aren't offensive) but simply de-listed from the site and search results.” - Questions are linkable and viewable even when deleted as a registered user if you are the author. The question was deleted because it was about Facebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(As posted in Ask a Moderator Chat)

The question was posted as a guest, closed as Off Topic, then deleted by the site cleanup script. It was not a manual action.

The question text is below, and it is still Off Topic. I would recommend reading the "What topics can I ask about?" link in the Help Center to determine what questions we have here.

> I work for a company which has a Facebook page and which uses Facebook
> Business / Facebook Ads.
>
> Part of my job is managing Facebook product feed integrations and
> ensuring our products are being pulled into Facebook correctly.
>
> Until recently I was able to do all of this via a generic company
> Facebook account, e.g. `admin@example.com`.
>
> However a few weeks ago Facebook locked this account, presumably
> because it doesn't have any real content on it; it's just a generic
> login. To unlock the account, Facebook is requesting a phone number
> and then photographic identification.
>
> As an employee I have no interest whatsoever in providing Facebook
> with any of my personal information. In any case, such ID would not
> match the name on the account since - again - the account is a generic
> company one.
>
> Facebook has said in the past that all accounts must belong to a real
> person with a real name, that accounts cannot be shared, and that each
> person can only have a single account.
>
> In this respect it seems I'm left with a choice:
>
> 1. Get a personal Facebook account, provide Facebook with personal information and my ID, then use that account to manage my employer's
>    business page.
>
> or
>
> 2. Tell my employer I refuse to give any personal info to Facebook and risk pissing them off and looking unprofessional.
>
> What can I do about this? Is there any way to successfully use
> Facebook with a generic or shared account?
>
> P.S. as a web professional I find this extremely frustrating and I
> heavily criticise Facebook for forcing professionals to divulge their
> personal information in the course of fulfilling the duties of their
> job.